# Using 'Soft index file store' with infinispan

Tags: java, infinispan

I have trouble to use soft-index-file-store persistancec. This is the configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:7.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-7.0.xsd"
        xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:7.0">

    <cache-container default-cache="default">
        <local-cache name="default">
            <persistence>
                <soft-index-file-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:soft-index:7.0">
                    <index path="${user.dir}/index" />
                    <data path="${user.dir}/data" />
                </soft-index-file-store>
            </persistence>
        </local-cache>
    </cache-container>

</infinispan>
```

Dependencies:

```
<version.infinispan>8.2.4.Final</version.infinispan>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
    <artifactId>infinispan-embedded</artifactId>
    <version>${version.infinispan}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
    <artifactId>infinispan-persistence-soft-index</artifactId>
    <version>${version.infinispan}</version>
</dependency>
```

And start the cache by:

```
cache = new DefaultCacheManager("infinispan.xml").getCache();
```

And I get this error:

```
org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: ISPN000327: Cannot find a parser for element 'soft-index-file-store' in namespace 'urn:infinispan:config:soft-index:7.0'. Check that your configuration is up-to date for this version of Infinispan.
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The correct namespace is `urn:infinispan:config:store:soft-index:7.0` (or another version, preferrably 8.0 if you use 8.2.4.Final) - you've missed the **store** part.

I see that stable documentation points to wrong namespace, sorry about that.

Comment: It didn't work for both v7 & v8.  Error: `org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: ISPN000327: Cannot find a parser for element 'soft-index-file-store' in namespace 'urn:infinispan:config:store:soft-index:8.0'. Check that your configuration is up-to date for this version of Infinispan.`

Comment: Which version exactly are you using? This is 8.2: https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/8.2.x/persistence/soft-index/src/main/java/org/infinispan/persistence/sifs/configuration/SoftIndexFileStoreConfigurationParser72.java#L25

Comment: And 7.2.x uses the old (non-standard/incorrect) namespace: https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/7.2.x/persistence/soft-index/src/main/java/org/infinispan/persistence/sifs/configuration/SoftIndexFileStoreConfigurationParser70.java#L25